# How to avoid "too many redirects" error in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code in my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase /
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I want to redirect the domain from http to https. But when I try to do that I am getting the error "too many redirects" error.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend putting a simple Redirect statement in your main config file, in the http vhost, rather than using .htaccess files for this. There are nunerous reasons for this which are covered in more detail in the httpd FAQ.

```
Redirect / https://example.com/
```

We also recommend using FallbackResource for the front controller stuff

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: But i do not have access to http Vhost file.